# React Native Picker Component: How to style caret (small triangle in the right) ?

Tags: react-native

Very simple question :
How do you style this caret? (in the blue circle, it's a small black upside-down triangle). The `color: 'white'` style only works with the text inside the picker, no success with the caret so far.

I use React-native 0.55.2, this is a React Native Picker component: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#style

[image]

Comment: I think you can not change it , https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1976#issuecomment-404734041

Comment: probably you need to go for other library, example [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker) and since no arrow exists, then add it on your own with styleSheet

Answer (score 2):

inside your styles.xml file include that line working normally

#ffffff

Comment: <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#EFECEB</item>